# Сбросить/не применять запросы при переходах между страницами

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Есть SPA на Vue, также используется Vuex.

Проблема состоит в том, что нескольно страниц использують один и тот же стейт, и если на одной странице отправить запрос (сработает внутри vuex) и быстро перейти на другую, то при переходе сработает очистка стейта, а уже потом прийдет ответ от сервера, и запишет данные для предедущей страницы. Особенно заметно при медленном соединении.

Есть ли какая-то возможность не применять ответ, если мы перейшли на другую страницу, но при этом ответы с данной страницы применять?
Проверка роута выглядит костыльно, так как не для всех запросов такая проверка нужна и такой код внесет хаос в уже и так немалый десяток запросов.
Были варианты использовать сторонние библиотеки, чтоб отменять промисы, но это крайний вариант. Использовать разный стейт для разных страниц тоже не вариант.

Comment: ну так 2-й ответ должен же перетереть 1-й?

Comment: @Дмытрык да, если на второй странице отправить запрос, но если не отправлять, то будуть данные с другой страницы

Comment: ну так, если у Вашей старницы есть логика, которая определяет отправлять запрос или нет, то и обработайте там ситуацию, когда страница запрос не отправила, но какие-то данные в store есть

Comment: @Дмытрык я знаю что это нужно сделать, вопрос и заключается в том как это сделать без боли, запросов много и проверок будет много

Comment: Устранение недостатков архитектуры зачастую причиняет боль.

Comment: Код вставьте, который вы используете